# concatenating with crossfade several videos (with audio)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've got 7 short video clips that are all the same size, frame rate, etc.  I want to concatenate them one after another with 2 seconds crossfade, and not lose audio.  Taken from an earlier post here I've tried just concatenating/crossfading the first two using:

```
ffmpeg -i *clip1.mp4 -i *clip2.mp4  \
-filter_complex "[0]fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0]; \
[1]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va1];  \
[va0][va1]overlay[outv];[0][1]amix[outa]" \
-map [outv] -map "[outa]" -crf 10 out.mp4
```

However, this produces a video that immediately fades out the first video, and ends up exactly the same length as the second video (which happens to be 40 seconds).  I assume that this is because of "st=0" for the first video [0]?  However, if I change that to "st=18" (the first video is 20 seconds long), the resulting combined video (out.mp4) still has the first video immediately fading (and the whole video is still only 40 seconds long instead of 58). However, the audio for the first one does now last 18 seconds (but it is now overlaying the second video and its audio for 18 seconds). Any suggestions of what to try?

Answer (score 1):

For joining with clips with crossfades - you need to take care of two things - apply the fade at the correct time and of the correct type, and delay the video timestamps so that each video starts at the correct time within the final assembly.

In this case, your first video is 20s, your second video is 40s, and you want a 2s crossfade. When executing crossfades using the overlay filter, we only need to apply fade-ins to the incoming video. Applying a fade-out to the outgoing video will produce a luminance dip - sometimes desirable, but I avoid it.

So, first, we apply a 2s fade **in** at the start of the second video.

```
[1]format=yuva444p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+18/TB[va1];
```

Since the fade is applied to the alpha channel only, the video needs to have an alpha channel. Typically, videos do not, so a pixel format conversion filter is applied before the fade to change the 2nd video's pixel format to one that has alpha - note the `a` in `yuva444p`. A fade of type `in` is applied starting at time `0` and of duration `2s` to the [alpha channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) only i.e. the video's color pixels aren't affected.

Now the 2nd video should be delayed. Since the 1st video is 20s long and a 2s crossfade is wanted, the 2nd video should start at 18s within the assembly. So the setpts filter is applied

```
setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+18/TB
```

The TB refers to the [timebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337235/5726027), and is the unit in which timestamps are stored for a stream.

For audio crossfades, there is an acrossfade filter

```
[0][1]acrossfade=d=2
```

This sets a crossfade of 2 seconds.

Now we can assemble the two clips,

```
ffmpeg -i *clip1.mp4 -i *clip2.mp4  \
-filter_complex \
 "[1]format=yuva444p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+18/TB[va1];  \
 [0][va1]overlay[outv];[0][1]acrossfade=d=2[outa]" \
-map [outv] -map "[outa]" -crf 10 out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works beautifully.  I seem to be stuck trying to get 3 strung together.  I tried: ffmpeg -i *clip1.mp4 -i *clip2.mp4  -i *clip3.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]format=yuva444p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+18/TB[va1];[2]format=yuva444p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+58/TB[va2];[0][va1]overlay[outv];[va1][va2]overlay[outv];[0][1]acrossfade=d=2[outa];[1][2]acrossfade=d=2[outa]" -map [outv] -map "[outa]" -crf 10 out7.mp4     But got "Invalid file index 2 in filtergraph description..."

Comment: The 2nd overlay has to use the output of the 1st overlay as its base. Same goes for acrossfade i.e. `[outv][va2]overlay[outv]` and `[outa][2]acrossfade=d=2[outa]`

Comment: that worked for the video portion, but the audio (for the third clip) was out of whack.  I ended up just repeatedly using the code you provided for 2 videos (e.g., clip1+clip2, then clip3+clip4, then [clip1+clip2]+[clip3+clip4], etc., until all 7 were joined.  Thanks very much for your help, and the great explanation.

Comment: Also, minor point: Your code for 2 clips needs a beginning quotation mark after -filter_complex (to match the one at the ends of the filter_complex code)